# Java File IO Exceptions

Tags: java, file, io

I am attempting to create a simple program that will keep a text log of collected data. To set  this up, I have the following code run at the start of the program (to set up the log file, and the tools to use it):

```
File logFile = new File("logs/logFile.txt");
FileWriter fw;
FileReader fr;
BufferedWriter writer;
BufferedReader reader;

public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println(logFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        logFile.createNewFile();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("WARNING: CANNOT CREATE FILE");
    }
    try{
        fw = new FileWriter("plugins/Stalker/log.txt");
        fr = new FileReader("plugins/Stalker/log.txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ERROR: CANNOT READ OR WRITE TO LOG FILE");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I hit both exceptions. It does not create either the file, or the folder (logs) at the path given in the first println. The path is as I expect it to be, and I SHOULD have write permissions for that directory (I know for a fact that other programs regularly write logs and such to a parent directory)... I've worked with files a little bit before, but it has been a bit, and I am at a complete loss here.

What sort of problem(s) might I be running into? What attempts at fixing this would you suggest?

Comment: The problems you are running into are included with the exceptions you get, you just need to print them. Use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks.

Comment: Does the absolute path exists? Are you running Unix-like OS ?

Comment: instead of printing your error messages if you actually print the message of the execption you would know what to do. use `e.getMessage()` instead of the un-helpful message you are printing yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with folders, you have to make sure that the folder exists.

For that you have to write a condition before `logFile.createNewFile();` to check whether the folder exists because createNewFild will not create folders.

You have to modify the program little bit like this.

```
File logFileFolder = new File("logs");
File stalkerFolder = new File("plugins/Stalker");
File logFile = new File("logs/logFile.txt");
FileWriter fw;
FileReader fr;
BufferedWriter writer;
BufferedReader reader;

public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println(logFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        if (!logFileFolder.exists()){
             // Create folder if does not exist
             logFileFolder.mkdir();
        }
        logFile.createNewFile();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("WARNING: CANNOT CREATE FILE");
    }
    try{
        if (!stalkerFolder.exists()){
             // Create folders if does not exist
             stalkerFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        fw = new FileWriter("plugins/Stalker/log.txt");
        fr = new FileReader("plugins/Stalker/log.txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ERROR: CANNOT READ OR WRITE TO LOG FILE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` method available in `File` to test if it exists or not.

If I remember correctly, `FileWriter` creates a file if it does not exist already. Check the other constructors for appending.

However, I think the problem you are facing is because you haven't closed writing the file, before you attempt to read it.

Inorder to flush to the stream, you need to call [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29)

Additionally, like Ravindra Gullapalli mentioned, you also need to check if the folder exist before attempting to create files. If not, you need to create them using [mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) method.