# File neither created nor throwing errors

Tags: java

```
//PRE-SET VARIABLES: symbolsToCheck, time
for (String s : symbolsToCheck) {
    String fileName = "daylogs-" + time + "/" + s + ".txt";
    File daylog = new File(fileName);
    if (!daylog.exists()) {
      if (!daylog.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR creating day log for " + s);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Day log created: " + daylog.getCanonicalPath());
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("ERROR day log already exists for " + s);
    }
  }
```

Nothing is outputted from this, and I've confirmed that symbolsToCheck is populated (roughly a dozen strings). I can also confirm that `time` is set (integer timestamp) well before this code snippet is called. Been scratching my head for quite some time now, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? What are the results?

Comment: Thats obvious then, there's no String s in symbolsToCheck.Period.

Comment: Are you looking in the correct directory?  It looks like you're using just a file name, so the file should be created in the executing directory.

Comment: @Tom I hadn't it appears there is an uncaught `ClassNotFoundException` for `java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()`. @zybergu I stated in the ticket I confirmed there are strings in that variable.

Comment: Just add `System.out.println("Creating file " + s);` in the beginning of the loop and you will know.

Comment: @Chris Just like you forgot to mention uncaught exception, right?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I have tried that, it prints file data for each file but nothing within the file creation confirmation or failure if/then clauses.

Comment: @Chris How can you run your program if you have this exception? Or, how have you noticed, that this program doesn't create the files?

Comment: @Tom the program is compiling and running perfectly (well, no runtime errors) from Terminal in its current state. There is a bit of code later on in the program that relies on these files existing and will print a message for each missing file (in this case, all of them). Thanks to your initial suggestion I've figured out what the issue is and have resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution from a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838900/java-file-io-exceptions) and [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom)'s suggestion, I've determined that the file creation is breaking due to my attempts to create a new folder and file at the same time, which does not work with `createNewFile()`. I followed the suggested in the related post and file creation works as expected now.